# Why does data from Firestore DB returns as 'null' in FirestoreRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

After being successful with writing and reading data from Firestore, I am now trying to display that data in a `RecyclerView` by utilizing FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. However, in my `onBindViewHolder`, where I'm trying to set a textView with data from the database, I'm getting a NullPointerException, where my Client name is null.

Here is my FirestoreAdapter class:

```
public class FirestoreAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ServiceOrder, FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public FirestoreAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceOrder> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ServiceOrder model) {
        holder.osIdItem.setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position).getId()));
        holder.osClientItem.setText(getItem(position).getClient().getName()); //Line with error
        holder.osDateItem.setText(getItem(position).getDate());
        holder.osValueItem.setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position).getTotalValue()));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_os_item, parent, false);

        return new FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private  TextView osIdItem;
        private  TextView osClientItem;
        private  TextView osDateItem;
        private  TextView osValueItem;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            osIdItem =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.osIDItem);
            osClientItem =   itemView.findViewById(R.id.osClientNameItem);
            osDateItem =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.osDateItem);
            osValueItem =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.osValueItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Logcat

```
 2022-09-09 09:58:38.479 1147-1147/com.leonardomaito.autocommobile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.leonardomaito.autocommobile, PID: 1147
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.leonardomaito.autocommobile.models.Client.getName()' on a null object reference
        at com.leonardomaito.autocommobile.adapters.FirestoreAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirestoreAdapter.java:27)
        at com.leonardomaito.autocommobile.adapters.FirestoreAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirestoreAdapter.java:18)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java:157)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:2028)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:417)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:655)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

My `Client` class is using a Builder design pattern, along with the default constructor as required by Firestore, and a Parcelable for transfering data through Activities, I'm only adding this since I'm not sure if it could impact how Firestore is reading my data.

So, how come I can use read and write data to the database, but I can't seem to display it? I have a `Client` 'name' in my database, shouldn't it be displaying that?

If it helps, my `ServiceOrder`  class requires a `Vehicle` and a `Client` object in order to be built.

This is how my data is structured in Firestore:

[Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y32DB.png)

[Part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R5y2.png)

Thank you.

**EDIT**

As requested, the Firestore Reference:

```
public class OsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirestoreAdapter listAdapter;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference osRef = db.collection("cliente");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_os);


        setupRecyclerView();

        }

        private void setupRecyclerView() {

            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewOs);

            Query query = osRef.orderBy("ServiceOrder",
                    Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceOrder> options =
                    new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ServiceOrder>()
                            .setQuery(query, ServiceOrder.class)
                            .build();

            listAdapter = new FirestoreAdapter(options);


            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        listAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        listAdapter.stopListening();
    }
```

Ran another debugger and got the following message `No setter/field for ServiceOrder found on class com.leonardomaito.autocommobile.models.ServiceOrder`

**Database Schema**

[Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKiYv.png)

**ServiceOrder Class**

```
public class ServiceOrder {

    public Client client;
    public Vehicle vehicle;
    private String service;
    private String observation;
    private String paymentForm;
    private String date;
    private double totalValue;
    private int id;

    public ServiceOrder() {
    }

    private ServiceOrder(ServiceOrderBuilder serviceOrderBuilder){
        this.client = serviceOrderBuilder.client;
        this.vehicle = serviceOrderBuilder.vehicle;
        this.service = serviceOrderBuilder.service;
        this.paymentForm = serviceOrderBuilder.paymentForm;
        this.observation = serviceOrderBuilder.observation;
        this.totalValue = serviceOrderBuilder.value;
        this.date = serviceOrderBuilder.date;

    }



    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public double getTotalValue() {
        return totalValue;
    }

    public void setTotalValue(double totalValue) {
        this.totalValue = totalValue;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

   public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Vehicle getVehicle() {
        return vehicle;
    }

    public void setVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }

    public String getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(String service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public String getObservation() {
        return observation;
    }

    public void setObservation(String observation) {
        this.observation = observation;
    }

    public String getPaymentForm() {
        return paymentForm;
    }

    public void setPaymentForm(String paymentForm) {
        this.paymentForm = paymentForm;
    }

    public static class ServiceOrderBuilder {

        private Vehicle vehicle;
        private Client client;
        private final String service;
        private final String paymentForm;
        private final int id;
        private final double value;
        private final String date;
        private String observation;

        public ServiceOrderBuilder(Client client, Vehicle vehicle,
                                   String service, String paymentForm,
                                   int id, double value, String date) {
            this.client = client;
            this.vehicle = vehicle;
            this.service = service;
            this.paymentForm = paymentForm;
            this.id = id;
            this.value = value;
            this.date = date;
        }

        public ServiceOrder.ServiceOrderBuilder observation(String observation) {
            this.observation = observation;
            return this;
        }

        public ServiceOrder build() {
            ServiceOrder serviceOrder = new ServiceOrder(this);
            return serviceOrder;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting NPE?

Comment: @AlexMamo At `holder.osClientItem.setText(getItem(position).getClient().getName());`

Interestingly enough, all of them are 'null' if I debug my code, but I set my ID and totalValue as 0 to avoid NPE.

Comment: So most likely `getItem(position).getClient()`, returns null, right?

Comment: Correct. Had to use toString(), but it returns null all the same.

Comment: I believe the adapter is the first code I added on my post, the class being named `FirestoreAdapter` .

The edit has the Database(Firestore)Reference you requested.

As for the Export JSON, I unfortunately can only post it later, as it requires that I register a Credit Card in order to do so. Hopefully I can help with something else.

Comment: Ok, looking forward to seeing your schema.

Comment: It seems that Firestore Database doesn't allow to export as JSON, only offering to export my Schema as a metadata through GCS Bucket.

Comment: A simple screenshot would be fine.

Comment: Would the two screenshots referencing how my data is structured in Firestore suffice? They are just above the EDIT section in my post.

Comment: It won't, show us the database schema, not the structure of the document.

Comment: Added as requested. It could have something to do with the way I'm saving/reading the nested data?

Comment: I was referring to a screenshot from your Firebase Console.

Comment: Apologies, this is all very new to me. I have deleted the former edit and added a screenshot of the Firebase Console. Hopefully this is what you need.

Comment: And the last thing, please also add the content of your `ServiceOrder` class.

Comment: Added. I left in the getters/setters in case something could be wrong with them.

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the Firebase-UI library, when you're using the following method call:

```
.setQuery(query, ServiceOrder.class)
```

It means that you're trying to map all documents that are returned by the query into objects of type `ServiceOrder`. But this is actually not possible because your actual document looks like this:

```
clienteTeste (document)
  |
  --- ServiceOrder (map)
        |
        --- client: {...} (map)
        |
        --- date: "09/09/2022"
        |
        --- //other fields
```

Instead of this:

```
clienteTeste (document)
  |
  --- client: {...} (map)
  |
  --- date: "09/09/2022"
  |
  --- //other fields
```

See, there is no `ServiceOrder` extra object? This would be the simplest solution for solving this issue, in which the fields should be added directly into the document **not** inside a map.

If you however cannot change the document structure, which I doubt, since there is only one (test) document present there, then you should consider using encapsulation by creating another class with a single field called `ServiceOrder` which should be of type `ServiceOrder`. And then map each document into an object of this new class.

**Edit:**

According to your last comment, at the minimum, the class should look like this:

```
public class ServiceDocument {
    private ServiceOrder serviceOrder;

    public ServiceDocument() {}

    public ServiceDocument(ServiceOrder serviceOrder) {
        this.serviceOrder = serviceOrder;
    }

    @PropertyName("ServiceOrder")
    public getServiceOrder() {
        return serviceOrder;
    }
}
```

Now you should map all documents into an object of type `ServiceDocument`.

Comment: So the simplest solution would be to add `client`, `vehicle` and the `ServiceOrder` fields directly and separately instead of trying to add them into a  `ServiceOrder` object and sending only it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Alternatively, I could create a class which the constructor would receive a `Client` object, a  `Vehicle` object and finally a  `ServiceOrder` object? Akin to

classConstructor(Client client, Vehicle vehicle, ServiceOrder os){
this....
}

And thus add a object of this class into Firestore? Sorry to further bother you with this.

Comment: No, a class which should contain a single field. The name of the field should be `ServiceOrder`, as it already exists in the database, and the type should be `ServiceOrder`. Why would you need that, is only to map it directly. Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10) will help.

Comment: Could you further elaborate on this? I created the class with the field `ServiceOrder`, but I'm unsure on what should I do next. Would I have to use this in the FirestoreAdapter, or where I'm actually sending the ServiceOrder object?

I read the resource and I understood what you meant, but it seems to be different when using the FirestoreAdapter to read the data.

Comment: Try to solve the problem with the simplest solution. If still want to do it like that, please check my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Almost. I feel like using the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` is actually limiting me in terms of how I can manipulate the data.

In most examples, including your blogpost, the task and `DocumentSnapshot` are used to map the documents in an object of `Class`. However, by using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`, it simply queries the document and I have no need for the snapshot method.

I did try to write the data as a `ServiceDocument`, but it only created another ServiceOrder in my database, such as:

-ServiceOrder
 |
  -ServiceOrder
   |
    - other fields...

Comment: That's not for writing data, but for reading it. Try to read the data in the screenshot using an object of type `ServiceDocument`. Does it work that way?

Comment: Gave it a try, but still had NPE. I guess I'm not experienced enough to get this done correctly, cause I must be missing something obvious. I did thought about going for the simplest solution, but then how would I be able to get data from 3 different models when onBindViewHolder only accepts one?

I'm at a loss here.

Comment: In general, other questions that derive from the initial question should be considered new questions and should be added separately, here on StackOverflow. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial issue?

Comment: I believe that for the time being, no. I will be reading this post again and again trying to come up with a solution, but I might have to create a new post regarding new issues that might arise. Thank you for your time Alex.

Comment: If you have a hard time implementing a solution, then show us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with what you have tried, and this way, I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Taff and nice question btw ;)