# Mapping documents into an object of a class to use with FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

## **Context**

I've been attempting to display data from Firestore in a `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`, however this data is basically nested Maps, so a direct approach using the `Query` function is not ideal. Here is an image of my **data structure**:

[image: Firestore Data Structure]

Notice that `ServiceOrder`, `client` and `vehicle` are all Maps. In my Java code, `ServiceOrder` is made up of a `Client` and `Vehicle` objects.

So, if I were to use `.setQuery(query, ServiceOrder.class)`, it would attempt to Map all of the data into `ServiceOrder` objects. But since my document is structured the way it is, that is not possible.

## **Issue**

I suppose this could be fixed by mapping all documents into an object of a new class, similar to what is done here: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10.

Even though I can see how it could be done using a normal RecyclerView and using a custom adapter, could the same solution be used in `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`? Because I did try to create something akin to the solution in the link, but couldn't get it to work.

## **My code**

Here is where I'm setting up the RecyclerView and Querying the data from Firestore:

```
 private void setupRecyclerView() {

            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewOs);

            Query query = osRef.orderBy("ServiceOrder",
                    Query.Direction.ASCENDING); //This is the issue.
                     //How could I map the documents here?

            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceOrder> options =
                    new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ServiceOrder>()
                            .setQuery(query, ServiceOrder.class)
                            .build();

            listAdapter = new FirestoreAdapter(options);

            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
```

My FirestoreRecyclerAdapter, where I'm binding my Views. The `onBindViewHolder` returns NPE for every View. This is the problem with the nested Maps described early.

```
public class FirestoreAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ServiceOrder, FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ServiceOrder model) {
        holder.osIdItem.setText(String.valueOf(model.getId()));
        holder.osClientItem.setText(model.getPaymentForm());
        holder.osDateItem.setText(model.getPaymentForm());
        holder.osValueItem.setText(String.valueOf(model.getTotalValue()));
    }
```

And finally, my `ServiceOrder` class. **Getters/Setters were removed to increase readability.**

```
public class ServiceOrder {

    public Client client;
    public Vehicle vehicle;
    private String service;
    private String observation;
    private String paymentForm;
    private String date;
    private double totalValue;
    private int id;

    public ServiceOrder() {
    }

    private ServiceOrder(ServiceOrderBuilder serviceOrderBuilder){
        this.client = serviceOrderBuilder.client;
        this.vehicle = serviceOrderBuilder.vehicle;
        this.service = serviceOrderBuilder.service;
        this.paymentForm = serviceOrderBuilder.paymentForm;
        this.observation = serviceOrderBuilder.observation;
        this.totalValue = serviceOrderBuilder.value;
        this.date = serviceOrderBuilder.date;

    }

    public static class ServiceOrderBuilder {

        private Vehicle vehicle;
        private Client client;
        private final String service;
        private final String paymentForm;
        private final int id;
        private final double value;
        private final String date;
        private String observation;

        public ServiceOrderBuilder(Client client, Vehicle vehicle,
                                   String service, String paymentForm,
                                   int id, double value, String date) {
            this.client = client;
            this.vehicle = vehicle;
            this.service = service;
            this.paymentForm = paymentForm;
            this.id = id;
            this.value = value;
            this.date = date;
        }


        public ServiceOrder.ServiceOrderBuilder observation(String observation) {
            this.observation = observation;
            return this;
        }

        public ServiceOrder build() {
            ServiceOrder serviceOrder = new ServiceOrder(this);
            return serviceOrder;

        }
    }
}
```

## **My attempt**

As suggested in another post, I attempted to create a new `ServiceOrderDocument` in order to map all documents into an object of this class. The class:

```
public class ServiceOrderDocument {

        ServiceOrder serviceOrder;

        public ServiceOrderDocument() {}

        public ServiceOrderDocument(ServiceOrder serviceOrder) {
            this.serviceOrder = serviceOrder;
        }

        @PropertyName("ServiceOrder")
        public ServiceOrder getServiceOrder() {
            return serviceOrder;
        }
    }
```

Ànd pass this into the Adapter found in the `private void setupRecyclerView()`. However, the Adapter expects a `QuerySnapshot`, so I feel like I'm stuck here.

## **Reproducing the issue**

If you'd like to try it out yourself, the best way would be to have three Classes, with one of them having objects from the other two. A example would be a `Sale` class having objects from `Salesman` and `Product`.

Proceed to write a `Sale` object into your Firestore database, and see how it creates a nested document. Then, try to display that `Sale` in a RecyclerView using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. Your `onBindViewHolder` should have a `Sale` model that would get the data from it's getters.

## **Edit**

So using a List to get the content seems to work at a first glance, by using `Cast` I could pass it as a adapter for the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`, however, it does not work for the `startListening()` methods. Here's what I did:

```
 private void setupRecyclerView() {

        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    services = document.toObject(ServiceOrderDocument.class).services;

                    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewOs);
                    Query query = osRef.orderBy("ServiceOrder",
                            Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

                    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceOrder> options =
                            new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ServiceOrder>()
                                    .setQuery(query, ServiceOrder.class)
                                    .build();

                    // listAdapter = new FirestoreAdapter(options);
                    services = (List<ServiceOrder>) new FirestoreAdapter(options);

                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new  LinearLayoutManager(this));
                    recyclerView.setAdapter((RecyclerView.Adapter) services);

                }
            }
        });
        }
```

However, the following issue is created:

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        listAdapter.startListening();//NPE Error
        services.startListening();//Can't use method
    }
```

Comment: The Adapter expects a QuerySnapshot, that's correct. Be sure to be of the correct `ServiceOrderDocument` type. This question is some kind of duplicate, but I will not close it, as maybe someone will try to explain it better than I did.

Comment: Since you're the one who wrote the blogpost I linked, I could use `ServiceOrderDocument` as a parameter to `toObject()`, but how could I go about making sure it works as an Adapter for `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`?

Comment: The blog post indicates how to do that with an array, not with an object (map). But you can achieve the exact same thing using an object, and you can each document in your adapter class to an object of type `ServiceOrderDocument`. But in my opinion, the first solution will be much simpler.

Comment: I decided to try the simple solution first, using the array. With some type casting I managed to use a List and pass it as an Adapter to `FirestoreRecylerAdapter`. However, I can't use the `startListening()` method anymore. Check the Edit for more information on my attempt.

Comment: `startListening()` is a part of the Firebase UI library. However, you can attach and detach the lister as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861350/should-i-actually-remove-the-valueeventlistener/48862873).

Comment: I see. Will try it out. Just did some testing and my code doesn't actually run since `FirestoreAdapter cannot be cast to java.util.List`. I'm going to have to look for another solution.

Comment: That's the expected behavior, you can't cast a an object of type FirestorAdaper into a List.

Comment: Then how exactly am I supposed to use my `ServiceOrderDocument`? Or the List `services`, in this case?

Comment: Set the type of the adapter to be ServiceOrderDocument.

Comment: @AlexMamo that worked. I'm not sure what I was doing before, but once I set the adapter to be ServiceOrderDocument, and made the correspondent changes, I got the data I need into the Recycler.

I'm going to post it as an answer in case another user stumbles upon this issue.

Comment: There is already an answer in the earlier question of yours. Besides that, the solution is already provided in the last comment above.

Comment: My bad, I just felt like gathering all that information into a single answer, but I don't mind if it is deleted.

Comment: I was referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73662910/why-does-data-from-firestore-db-returns-as-null-in-firestorerecycleradapter/73694519#73694519), as it provides the solution to your problem, right?

Comment: Correct. I had to make some changes to other parts of the code, but that is the overall solution.

Comment: So it's good to hear that. Can I help with other information regarding that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73662910/why-does-data-from-firestore-db-returns-as-null-in-firestorerecycleradapter/73694519#73694519)?

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an answer, read Alex Mamo comments and his post at:
https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10.

For my solution, I did need a `ServiceDocument` class to help me map my documents so I could use it in my Adapter. This is what the class looks like:

```
public class ServiceDocument {

    public ServiceOrder serviceOrder;

    public ServiceDocument() {
    }

    @PropertyName("serviceOrder")
    public ServiceOrder getServiceOrder() {
        return serviceOrder;
    }
}
```

Then, in your Activity or wherever you are managing your Recyler/Adapter, you would need something like this

```
    Query query = osRef.orderBy("serviceOrder",
                 Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

   FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceDocument> options =
    new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ServiceDocument>()
                                    .setQuery(query, ServiceDocument.class)
                                    .build();

    listAdapter = new FirestoreAdapter(options);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Last but not least, make sure your Adapter class has been adapted for your new class.

```
public class FirestoreAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ServiceDocument, FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public FirestoreAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceDocument> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ServiceDocument model) {
        holder.osIdItem.setText(String.valueOf(model.getServiceOrder().getId()));
        holder.osClientItem.setText(model.getServiceOrder().getClient().getName());
        holder.osDateItem.setText(model.getServiceOrder().getDate());
        holder.osValueItem.setText(String.valueOf(model.getServiceOrder().getTotalValue()));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_os_item, parent, false);

        return new FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }
```